Using Criteria Builder to compare Year with full date
I'm using criteria builder and predicate to filter a search with the specified parameters recieved from front end and I've been strugling to make the year part work.
I have a full date stored in the db but I want to receive only the year from the front end.
As I have other parameters already using the predicate and criteria builder I would want to still keep using it, but I'm open to suggestions.
if(yearCreated.isPresent()) {
   predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.localDate() root.<LocalDate>get("yearCreated"),
   LocalDate.ofYearDay(Integer.valueOf(yearCreated.get()), 1) ));
}

I've been trying all sorts of uses from criteriaBuilder, the closest I got was with criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo but it brings more results than it should because of the greaterThan.

One common way is to compute in the code the first day and the last day of the given year and create two predicates >= first and <= last

It sure did work, I thought there could be another more direct way of doing it, but It did the job, thanks for the help Turo
